# How do I change the value of a select box field of a certain entry through the front-end?

Tags: frontend, saveentry

So I'm having this entry (a product) that contains a selectbox field with two values:

- Reserved
- Available

By default this field is set to 'Available', but when the user lands on a certain page (a thank you page after "ordering" this product with the entry id as a querystring in the URL), I'd like to change the value of that selectbox to 'Reserved'.

Anyone can put me in the right direction on this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to resave the entry or just want to display certain things based on url parameter? Do you want it to save automatically or do you want to create a form?

Comment: Resaving the entry automatically at page load of the "/thank-you?id=33" page (with 33 being the entry id of that product)

Comment: Do you want to use twig or would you use PHP for it?

Comment: Twig, please! If PHP can be avoided, the better :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Twig

You can check for certain URL parameters via

```
{% set param = craft.app.getRequest().getParam('id') %}
{% if param is not null %}
    {% set entry = craft.app.getElements().getElementById(param) %}
    {# insert your new field value! not the label, the value/handle
    {% do entry.setFieldValue('fieldHandle', 'Reserved') %}
    {% do craft.app.getElements().saveElement(entry) %}
{% endif %}
```

However I would not recommend doing this in Twig

#### PHP

You can see how to use [Template Variables](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/variables.html#app) and create your boilerplate at [pluginfactory.io](http://pluginfactory.io)

```
{% do craft.myAwesomePlugin.saveEntry(entry, {fieldHandle: 'yourValue'}) %}
```

And your function could be

```
public function saveEntry($entry, $attributes = []){
    $entry->getContent()->setAttributes($attributes);
    craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
}
```

That's just a "quick" version, I suggest you to take a look at `EntriesController` to see how Craft handles it in detail

Comment: Thanks! I can see by the "craft.app.xxx" that this is Craft 3 code? The project still runs on Craft 2, is this also available in 2?
Why wouldn't you recommend doing this in Twig?

Comment: No it does not work in Craft 2 - Twig is a template engine and not supposed to contain to much logic. You only have limited opportunities for error handling so if something unexpected happens you can't handle it really well

Comment: Yes, I understand, you asked if I wanted to use Twig or PHP so I thought I had a choice and would avoid PHP if possible :) Can you set me on the way on how to do this with Craft 2? I assume this needs a custom plugin? I'm not afraid to write some PHP code, but just need to know some steps in order to get this done

Comment: I've edited the answer